# Moving from one user to another in MySql

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

To login into mysql, in ubuntu we have a option from terminal like

```
  shell# mysql -uxxx -pyyyy;
```

Now, I would be as "XXX" user in mysql. and terminal would be like

```
  mysql>
```

Now, I want to enter into mysql as a different user(Eg: YYY user) from here itself without quitting.

Is there any way?
 Appreciate if any help.

Comment: IMHO there is no way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to quit. But there are some interesting perspectives in this similar question [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/526/can-you-su-in-mysql).